# Having a distribution group with in another distribution group to redirect emails

Tags: email, active-directory

We have two email addresses for some groups due to translations so people can email both addresses but still go to the same people.  Rather than having two distr groups for the two languages and each of them having all of the members in them (which would just make a lot of duplicates), we would want one of the groups to be inside the other so it's easier to manage the groups.

In active directory is there a way of having a distribution group with two email addresses or having a distribution group within another distr group so the emails get redirected from one address to the other?
Any suggestions for other ways of doing it if it's not possible in Active directory as well

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can assign as many email addresses to a group (or a user) as you want.

Assuming you're using Exchange, the attribute is `proxyAddresses`. Each address begins with the protocol. For email, that's `SMTP:`. The primary address has it in upper case. Any secondary addresses are in lower case.

So just add another address with lower case `smtp:`.

Your `proxyAddresses` list will look something like this:

```
SMTP:primaryaddress@example.com
smtp:secondaryaddress@example.com
```

You can either add it using the attribute editor in AD Users and Computers, or through Exchange PowerShell:

```
Set-DistributionGroup "Group Name" -EmailAddresses @{Add="smtp:secondaryaddress@example.com"}
```